# Different users for Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on a Laravel project that requires a home owner to log in to the website. Then, he/she is required to fill a form on guest details. When he/she submits the form, it will be displayed in a list. Now, when a home owner submits a form, every other home owner can see it too. How can I make it so that only the logged in home owner able to see his/her list of guests? Is this possible to do?

My GuestController is as follows:

```
class GuestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //returns admin's view
        $guest = Guest::all();
        return view('pages.guest.index', compact('guest'));
    }

    public function show()
    {
        //returns a home owner's view
        $guest = Guest::all();
        return view('pages.guest.show', compact('guest'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.guest.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $guest = new Guest;
        $guest->code = random_int(100000, 999999);
        $guest->hash = hash('sha256', $guest['code']);        
        $guest->owner = Auth::user()->name;
        $guest->unit = Auth::user()->unit;
        $guest->guestname = $request->input('guestname');
        $guest->guestphone = $request->input('guestphone');
        $guest->guestic = $request->input('guestic');
        $guest->guestcar = $request->input('guestcar');
        $guest->datevisit = $request->input('datevisit');
        $guest->timevisit = $request->input('timevisit');
        $guest->save();
        
        return redirect('show-pass')->with('status', 'Guest Added Successfully');
    }
```

Comment: Use `Guest::where('owner', <the currently logged in owner>)` instead of `Guest:all()` ? Maybe, I'm still not 100% sure I understood the problem

Comment: I'm pretty sure you get what I meant. Let say, a home owner named Adam logs in the website, so he can only see his list of guests. If another home owner named Jack logs in the website, he can only see his, not Adam's.

Comment: what are you saving in $request->input('owner'); owner name or id ?

Comment: @AqibJaved owner's name. But I've already changed it. Wait, let me edit my question then I'll get back to you.

Comment: If you set up your model relations correct you can do something like `auth()->user()->guests` to get the guests related to the currently logged in user. `Guest::all()` will get ... _all_ guests in your system

Comment: @AqibJaved my owner's name is in a table named 'users' under the column 'name'.

Comment: @brombeer can you explain more to me? I have two models here: User and Guest. In which model do I have to put ```auth()->user()->guests```?

Comment: The Laravel documentation has a pretty decent page on [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships). That code should replace any code where you want to get the currently logged in users guests - in your case it should replace `Guest:all()` - in your Controller, not in a Model

Comment: @brombeer thank you, your answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. I am expecting this function will call when a user other than admin login and want to see list of his guests. Please check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses) as well.

```
 public function show()
    {
        //returns a home owner's view
        $guest = Guest::where('owner',Auth::user()->name)->get();
        return view('pages.guest.show', compact('guest'));
    }
```

Comment: I can now understand how to use ```Auth::user()```. Thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

At the database level, make the owner a foreign key on the `guests` table. I am guessing that the owners belong to `users` table, so you will have something like this in your migration file

```
//...
Schema::create('guests', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
    $table->bigUnsignedInteger('code');
    //...
});
```

So your store method will be as

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $guest = new Guest;
    $guest->code = random_int(100000, 999999);     
    $guest->user_id = Auth::id();
    //...
    
    return redirect('show-pass')->with('status', 'Guest Added Successfully');
}
```

And then your index() method will be

```
public function index()
{
    //returns admin's view
    $guest = Guest::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
    return view('pages.guest.index', compact('guest'));
}
```

PS: you should define relationships in the respective `User` and `Guest` models to make things even smoother.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you store a form, make sure you store the logged user's ID too and not just the name. You may encounter problems in the future if there are multiple users with the same name.

For your `guests` database, you should create a column with `users` id as foreign key. Once you're able to do that and you name the column as `owner_id` for example, add this to your `store` function

```
$guest->owner_id = Auth::user()->id;
```

You can now do this with your `show` function

```
 public function show()
    {
        //returns a home owner's view
        $guest = Guest::where('owner_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        return view('pages.guest.show', compact('guest'));
    }
```

Comment: I did like what you said and it worked. Thank you!